# Recursive scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to rebuild some VBA functions in SQL server 2016 and I'm having difficult making a recursive function work properly.

My attempt below is returning `NULL` and when I step through the function in debug `@returnValue` never seems to hold a value even though it appears to recurse correctly.

Can someone please advise how to fix this.

Example expected results:

`select [dbo].TickDiff(1.01, 1.05) -- Expect result 4`

`select [dbo].TickDiff(2.02, 16) -- Expect result 121`

Functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].TickDiff (@odds1 float, @odds2 float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue as float
    IF (@odds1 > @odds2)
        BEGIN
            set @returnValue = @returnValue + [dbo].TickDiff([dbo].TicksDown(@odds1), @odds2) + 1
        END
    ELSE
        IF (@odds1 < @odds2)
        BEGIN
            set @returnValue = @returnValue + [dbo].TickDiff([dbo].TicksUp(@odds1), @odds2) + 1
        END
    RETURN @returnValue;
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].TicksUp(
    @odds float
)
RETURNS float
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    case 
        when @odds < 1 then 1.02
        when @odds >= 1 and  @odds <= 1.99 then @odds + 0.01
        when @odds >= 2 and  @odds <= 2.98 then @odds + 0.02
        when @odds >= 3 and  @odds <= 3.95 then @odds + 0.05
        when @odds >= 4 and  @odds <= 5.9 then @odds + 0.1
        when @odds >= 6 and  @odds <= 9.8 then @odds + 0.2
        when @odds >= 10 and  @odds <= 19.5 then @odds + 0.5
        when @odds >= 20 and  @odds <= 29 then @odds + 1.0
        when @odds >= 30 and  @odds <= 48 then @odds + 2.0
        when @odds >= 50 and  @odds <= 95 then @odds + 5.0
        when @odds >= 100 and  @odds < 1000 then @odds + 10
        when @odds >= 1000 then 1000
    end
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].TicksDown(
    @odds float
)
RETURNS float
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    case 
        when @odds <= 1.01 then 1.01
        when @odds >= 1.01 and  @odds <= 2 then @odds - 0.01
        when @odds >= 2.02 and  @odds <= 3 then @odds - 0.02
        when @odds >= 3.05 and  @odds <= 4 then @odds - 0.05
        when @odds >= 4.1 and  @odds <= 6 then @odds - 0.1
        when @odds >= 6.2 and  @odds <= 10 then @odds - 0.2
        when @odds >= 10.5 and  @odds <= 20 then @odds - 0.5
        when @odds >= 21 and  @odds <= 30 then @odds - 1.0
        when @odds >= 32 and  @odds <= 50 then @odds - 2.0
        when @odds >= 55 and  @odds <= 100 then @odds - 5.0
        when @odds >= 110 and  @odds < 1000 then @odds - 10
        when @odds >= 1000 then 990
    end
END
GO
```

The VBA functions I'm trying to copy are below:

```
Function TicksDown(ByVal odds As Currency) As Currency
    Dim IncrementOdds As Currency
    Select Case odds
        Case 1.01 To 2
            IncrementOdds = 0.01
        Case 2.02 To 3
            IncrementOdds = 0.02
        Case 3.05 To 4
            IncrementOdds = 0.05
        Case 4.1 To 6
            IncrementOdds = 0.1
        Case 6.2 To 10
            IncrementOdds = 0.2
        Case 10.5 To 20
            IncrementOdds = 0.5
        Case 21 To 30
            IncrementOdds = 1
        Case 32 To 50
            IncrementOdds = 2
        Case 55 To 100
            IncrementOdds = 5
        Case 110 To 1000
            IncrementOdds = 10
    End Select
    If Math.Round(odds - IncrementOdds, 2) >= 1.01 Then
        TicksDown = Math.Round(odds - IncrementOdds, 2)
    Else
        TicksDown = 1.01
    End If
End Function

Function TicksUp(ByVal odds As Currency) As Currency
    Dim IncrementOdds As Currency
    Select Case odds
        Case 1 To 1.99
            IncrementOdds = 0.01
        Case 2 To 2.98
            IncrementOdds = 0.02
        Case 3 To 3.95
            IncrementOdds = 0.05
        Case 4 To 5.9
            IncrementOdds = 0.1
        Case 6 To 9.8
            IncrementOdds = 0.2
        Case 10 To 19.5
            IncrementOdds = 0.5
        Case 20 To 29
            IncrementOdds = 1
        Case 30 To 48
            IncrementOdds = 2
        Case 50 To 95
            IncrementOdds = 5
        Case 100 To 1000
            IncrementOdds = 10
    End Select
    If Math.Round(odds + IncrementOdds, 2) <= 1000 Then
        TicksUp = Math.Round(odds + IncrementOdds, 2)
    Else
        TicksUp = 1000
    End If
End Function


Function TickDiff(odds1 As Currency, odds2 As Currency) As Long
    If odds1 > odds2 Then
            odds1 = TicksDown(odds1)
            TickDiff = TickDiff(odds1, odds2) + 1
    ElseIf odds1 < odds2 Then
            odds1 = TicksUp(odds1)
            TickDiff = TickDiff(odds1, odds2) + 1
    Else
        'Found, Exit Recursive Function
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: What is the function actually trying to Achieve here? It looks like it may well be overly complicated.

Comment: @Larnu - It's attempting to calculate the ticks between 2 odds on Betfair. They have different tick increments between ranges of odds. I didn't realise there were only 32 recursive levels allowed. Is best way to precalc the differences in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your @ReturnValue to zero:

```
DECLARE @returnValue as float = 0.0
```

That being said, your second example exceeds SQLs max recursion of 32.  You may want to rewrite without recursion.  Here's an example: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-217.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your  `@returnValue` is not initialized , so it is `null`. And

```
      set @returnValue = @returnValue + [dbo].TickDiff([dbo].TicksDown(@odds1), @odds2) + 1
```

evaluates to `null`.

Try

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].TickDiff (@odds1 float, @odds2 float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue as float = 0.;
    IF (@odds1 > @odds2)
        BEGIN
            set @returnValue = @returnValue + [dbo].TickDiff([dbo].TicksDown(@odds1), @odds2) + 1
        END
    ELSE
        IF (@odds1 < @odds2)
        BEGIN
            set @returnValue = @returnValue + [dbo].TickDiff([dbo].TicksUp(@odds1), @odds2) + 1
        END
    RETURN @returnValue;
END
```

Also `case` expressions can be simplified because sql-server evaluates `when` conditions in the order specified.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].TicksUp(
    @odds float
)
RETURNS float
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    case 
        when @odds < 1 then 1.02
        when @odds <= 1.99 then @odds + 0.01
        when @odds <= 2.98 then @odds + 0.02
        when @odds <= 3.95 then @odds + 0.05
        when @odds <= 5.9 then @odds + 0.1
        when @odds <= 9.8 then @odds + 0.2
        when @odds <= 19.5 then @odds + 0.5
        when @odds <= 29 then @odds + 1.0
        when @odds <= 48 then @odds + 2.0
        when @odds <= 95 then @odds + 5.0
        when @odds < 1000 then @odds + 10
        when @odds >= 1000 then 1000
    end
END
```